# Groupby entity joined with another Table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this scenario that I didnt find any solution looking through related SO questions :

```
  (from TD as tx 
   join P as px  on tx.field1= px.ID
   join Q as rp  on tx.field2 = rp.ID
   join L as lc  on tx.field3= lc.ID
    group by  tx.field1,
              tx.field2, 
              L.randomfield4,
              ....a bunch of fields from P,Q,L
   )as groupItem
   left outer join M on groupItem.field1=M.ID
   select new { */ Elements from groupItem and M /*}
```

My Linq looks as follows :

```
from tx in TD 
join itemP in P on tx.field1 equals P.ID
join itemQ in Q on tx.field2 equals P.ID
join itemL in L on tx.field3 equals P.ID
 group new { tx.field1 ,tx.field2 ,L.randomfield4 } by new { **fields from tx,p,q,etc} into groupItem 
 join dM in M on ????
```

If i try to select elements from groupItems I cannot access proprieties (because i didnt select anything ).

Can anyone help me with a starting point to this issue ?
  Also help me with a better name for the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully I understood your question correctly but here is my answer.  I divided the query into two so its easy to understand just combine them together if you fully get into it.

Basically the variable **"groupedCollection"** is your first joins and your grouping which basically includes the following collections TD, P, Q and L.  Then the second variable **"finalCollection"** is your left outer join which give the result you need.

```
var groupedCollection = from tx in TD
join itemP in P on tx.field1 equals itemP.ID
join itemQ in Q on tx.field2 equals itemQ.ID
join itemL in L on tx.field3 equals itemL.ID
group new
{   
    //Select the collections you want to group it by
    P,
    Q,
    L,
    TD
}
by new
{
    //Select fields you want to output group by here
    tx.field1,
    tx.field2,
    tx.field3,
    itemL.RandomField4
}
    into g
    select new
    {
        //Use ky to get your properties as they are already grouped by
        yourField1 = g.Key.field1,
        yourField2 = g.Key.field2,
        yourField3 = g.Key.field3,
        yourField4 = g.Key.RandomField4
    };

var finalCollection = from dM in M
    //This is your Left Outer Join
    join xx in groupedCollection on dM.ID equals xx.yourField1 into sr
    from w in sr.DefaultIfEmpty()
    //Until here
    select new
    {
        finalResultID = dM.ID,
        finalField1 = w.yourField1,
        finalField2 = w.yourField2,
        finalField3 = w.yourField3,
        finalField4 = w.yourField4
    };
```

for more LINQ stuff this will give you an idea
http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/linq-to-sql-essentials/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.From this I was able to solve my issue.U sir, deserve a cookie !